# Offensive post?

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing low quality posts and came across [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16234044). This was a test and I failed it. Now, whether or not I should have failed it is up for debate, but what I was told that this post was spam, rude or offensive. I agree it may be overly simplistic/brief and perhaps I should have failed the test. But offensive?

Comment: It's spam.  Spam bad.

Comment: But is it? Really? I agree spam is bad. Very bad. But what makes this spam?

Comment: "Now there is a tool Appuploader can be simple and fast ..." It is there merely to promote something: it is spam.

Comment: It's an account created to advertise a product, that's advertising a product.

Comment: @zondo But this tool seems to be in response to the question. Maybe I just don't understand enough about the question.

Comment: @MattCremeens The answer is just gibberish, and including random keywords from the question to try to give the vague impression that it's somehow related to the question, to try to get past spam filters (hence why we have humans evaluating potential spam, not just automated tools).  At a minimum you should be suspicious enough of something like this to take a closer look at the post and the account as it being possible spam, at which point it'd become clear that it's an audit.

Comment: I guess I just thought that the tool being suggested had something to do with the question being asked as a way to answer the question. My thinking now is that I must not have understood the question well enough in the first place.

Comment: ...I swear I'm seeing a different review than everyone else. I see a review for *a question* titled "how to renew an expired distribution certificate through the iOS provisioning portal" which has 45 upvotes and does not contain the phrase "now there is a tool Appuploader..."

Comment: @MattCremeens There are a lot of red flags that this is spam without needing to understand anything about the question.

Comment: @Draco18s: That's the question whose answer is being reviewed. Perhaps you can't see it because it's deleted now and you have <10k.

Comment: @zondo AH HA! Now it makes sense. When *I* see the review it just says "answer not found." :) Bingo. Unrelated, I am amused that the question is so heavily upvoted but the user barely has any rep (90% all from that question, which got a gold badge for being famous).

Comment: @Draco18s - Unfortunately, that's the case with any question about App Store submission and the various things that go wrong. We've had questions get dozens of upvotes just because someone asked about servers being down that day. Not to mention the flood of non-answers we have to clean up every time that happens.

Comment: @BradLarson Oh sure, I totally get it, it just amuses me. I mean heck, I once got insulted that I "was a member for 3 years and didn't even have 800 rep yet" (hilariously by a user who was himself under 100) because I was not active for those 3 years (take a look at my rep graph: I broke 1000 either the same day or the day after). I didn't even report the comment (although it has been deleted), I just laughed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As pointed out by others, it's spam. For non-10k users, this is what the post looked like:

[image: Spam post]

Be very suspicious of posts by new users that only promote a product in glowing terms, whether or not the product matches the subject of the question. Spammers seek out questions in the general areas of their products and post in them.

You didn't have this context, but this was the third account to spam this product from that location, and each account went on a bit of a spree:

[image: More spam]

These posts were flagged as spam, deleted by a moderator, and then the accounts were destroyed. The validated spam flags caused this to be used as an audit, and I think it's a good one. Answers like this should be subject to a little more review.

Comment: I am sure the context would have helped! Thanks for this answer.